# for loop issue with ajax success

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am calling ajax function inside for loop. But I am getting `1` inside ajax success. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0yd4x0aL/)

```
function a(){
var myAr= [0];
    for(var i=0; i<myAr.length;i++){
                console.log(i +" a")
    var root = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
        $.ajax({
          url: root + '/users',
          method: 'GET'
        }).then(function(data) {

        console.log(i + " c")

        });

                console.log(i + " b")
    }

}

a()
```

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code `console.log(i + " c")` only executed when ajax call is done. For this kind of functionality you have to trigger it in a different way.

Here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/0yd4x0aL/4/).

```
function a() {
   var myAr= [0, 2, 3];
   var startIndex = 0;

   var doAjaxCall = function(i) {
       console.log(i +" a");
       var root = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
        $.ajax({
          url: root + '/users',
          method: 'GET'
        }).then(function(data) {
            console.log(i + " c");
            if(i < (myAr.length - 1)) {
                i++;
                doAjaxCall(i);
            }
        });
   }

   doAjaxCall(startIndex);
}
a();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.then()` gets executed only when the response of the AJAX is received.

At that point, i is 1 because the foor loop is over.

If you want the original value when the AJAX request was created, you could create a new variable on the local scope with the value in `i`. That way, the closure executed inside the `.then()` method has the original value.

[Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/0yd4x0aL/2/)

Answer (score 1):

U have to use closure for this, otherwise it evaluate to last value of i executed

```
 function a(){
var myAr= [0];
  for(var i=0; i<myAr.length;i++){
            console.log(i +" a")
    var root = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
    $.ajax({
      url: root + '/users',
      method: 'GET'
    }).then(function(i) {return function(data) {
    console.log(i + " c")

    }}(i));

            console.log(i + " b")
}

}

a()
```